# SSRS 2008 Background colour based on values

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I am trying to use this expression to change the background colour of a text box within SSRS 2008

```
=IIF(Fields!Score.Value  <=12, "Green", IIF(Fields!Score.Value  >=13, "Amber"  , IIF(Fields!Score.Value  >=19, "Red"  ,"White")))
```

The result is 15 which should pull back an amber colour which it is not doing.

The thresholds for the score field are

High 19-24
Medium 13-18 
Low < 12

Answer (score 1):

Try to convert field value to INT, Might be expression considering this as string

```
=IIF(CInt(Fields!Score.Value) <=12, "Green", IIF(CInt(Fields!Score.Value) >=13, "Amber"  , IIF(CInt(Fields!Score.Value) >=19, "Red"  ,"White")))
```

Comment: Agreed but even then the Expression will not do what OP wants. It will only return Green for values smaller than 12 and Amber for values bigger the 12. Some more conditions are required: `=IIF(CInt(Fields!Score.Value)  <=12, "Green", 
 IIF(CInt(Fields!Score.Value)  >=13 AND CInt(Fields!Score.Value)  <19, "Amber"  , 
  IIF(CInt(Fields!Score.Value)  >=19 And CInt(Fields!Score.Value) <=24), "Red"  ,"White")
 )
)`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming 'Score' is an INT you just need to swap the tests for >= 13 and >=19 as follows:

```
=IIF(Fields!Score.Value  <=12, "Green", IIF(Fields!Score.Value  >=19, "Red"  , IIF(Fields!Score.Value  >=13, "Orange"  ,"White")))
```

Also 'Amber' isn't a valid colour name so change that to something like 'Orange' too.